# fit model with sd square

Tags: optimization

If I want to fit a nonlinear regression model with some parameters like $\sigma^2$(where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, which is positive), how can I guarantee that $\hat{\sigma}$ is positive?

I mean, if I use maximum likelihood(and the model only have square term of $\sigma$), how does the optimization method know $\sigma$ is positive? (well, it seems OK that the result estimation of $\sigma$ is negative, but it looks weird, and this is why I ask this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest parametrizing with a logarithm of volatility so you don't have to care about positivity, run the estimation and then invert back to original scale. Alternatively, you can consider constrained optimization routine. Without knowing more about the problem (at least the language you're using), that's about it.